# What is the "real" memory size occupied by a dynamic array?

Tags: delphi

#### Example:

```
procedure Test;
var
  AText: array of AnsiChar;
begin
  SetLength(AText, 7);
end;
```

#### Question

What is the *real* size of **AText** occupied in memory? Is it 7 + Cardinal size of its length, that is, 7 + 4 = 11 bytes?

Comment: Rudy Velthuis has an explanation of dynamic array layout: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#dynarrays

Comment: I'm Uli. Rudy wrote the article I linked to. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That plus 4 bytes reference count. And of course heapmanager overhead (which depends on delphi version and uses memory manager, which can easily be 12-16 bytes).

So that means:

- sizeof(element)*elementcount
- sizeof(refcount)

  - current implementations :sizeof(integer)=4
- sizeof(elementnumber)

  - FPC actually stores highest element, not elementcount. Don't know about Delphi)
  - current implementations :sizeof(integer)=4
- heap overhead.

  - At least the allocated size for the entire block.
  - Probably one or two pointers also (next block). But this depends on memory manager
  - many memory managers have a minimal blocksize of 16 or 32.

Comment: Thanks Marco. One more question, how about `array[0..7] of Char`?

Comment: @Astaroth: you should make that a separate question.

Comment: That's(in versions where `sizeof(char)=1`) just 8 bytes inlined into the containing type. No additional heap allocations.

Comment: Marco, why not: plus 8 bytes? (4 bytes refcount and 4 bytes length)?

Comment: CodeInChaos, yes, I maybe have made a confusion around the char size. I will correct it to Ansichar in my question.

Comment: @Jeroen, ok, I will post a another question.

Comment: A bit late, but the first sentence is in addition to the question, which already specifies the length (or high())