# What is the “real” memory size occupied by a static array?

Tags: delphi

This question has a relation with my previous question, [What is the “real” memory size occupied by a dynamic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448897/what-is-the-real-memory-size-occupied-by-a-dynamic-array)

#### Example:

```
var
  AText: array [0..6] of AnsiChar;
```

#### Question

What is the *real* size of **AText** occupied in memory? Is it really 7 bytes?

Comment: Note that these kinds of variables can also live on the stack, and if memory serves me right, those always take a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so. Maybe D2010+ adds some reference to the RTTI record.

Then there is also alignment, the next variable/field might not start directly after this variable/field leaving some slack bytes. (typically round up to some power of 2 like 16)

Note that alignment might be different for a local and a global variable, class var etc. The various segments all can have different alignment rules, and if it is a field/class var it might be different still.

Comment: You should also take into account the smallest block the memory manager can allocate

Comment: @user205376: FastMM is the default memory manager in recent Delphi versions, but you can compile with some other if you want.

Comment: 'Stack stuff' like local 'static' variables are not managed by FastMM (like this: array [0..6] of AnsiChar). Of course if you have local String/DynArray variable, then content is allocated by FastMM, but variable(pointer to String) in it-self is on stack.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is really 7 bytes